# Send multiple collections to elasticsearch using mongoDB input plugin for logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to send multiple collection data to elasticsearch using just one configuration file with the MongoDB input plugin for logstash.

Does anyone know how the configuration file should be?

Comment: here some https://code.likeagirl.io/5-different-ways-to-synchronize-data-from-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-d8456b83d44f

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    mongodb {
     uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
     placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
     placeholder_db_name => 'test.db'
     collection => 'collection1'
     batch_size => 5000
    }
    mongodb {
     uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
     placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
     placeholder_db_name => 'test.db'
     collection => 'collection2'
     batch_size => 5000
    }
```

or try this

```
    mongodb {
     uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
     placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
     placeholder_db_name => 'test.db'
     collection => (collection1|collection2)
     batch_size => 5000
    }
```